# Do not have the write permissions on files |directories after wordpress migration from hostgator to lightsail

Tags: php, wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

After migrating all the files in the public_html folder which i get from Hostgator to AWS Lightsail (bitnami wordpress pre-installed), even I still can login into /wp-admin with the old user name and password as well as seeing all the contents of the old website, I could not get the write permissons to the files for that user.

I am still having to the file permissons system set 775 for directory and 664 for files. I also set ftp method to direct in wp-config.php file.

If I set the folder permisson to 777, i can edit the files within wp-admin. However, 777 will make it more vulnerable to be attacked by hackers.

What should I do to obtain the write permissons for files and directories for my wordpress admin user?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Change the owner of the files to the user that your webserver runs as. It's usually www-data, but double-check the server to make sure.

Comment: Currently, bitnami user and deamon group is the owner of the server.

Answer (score 2):

Bitnami developer here. You can set the WordPress permissions and owner in the following way:

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon TARGET
sudo find TARGET -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find TARGET -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo chmod 640 TARGET/wp-config.php
```

Replacing TARGET with path to the WordPress folder.

Comment: Thanks for answering! is this a way to reset the file system permission?